# How to convert HTML with Ruby helper method ERB into Slim syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, slim-lang

Trying to convert some HTML code in a template to Slim syntax. The original code uses a Ruby helper method (in Rails) to dynamically determine the class of the `li` element.

Here is the original code in HTML:

```
<li class="<%= is_active_controller('dashboards') %>">
```

The online converter gives:

```
| <li class="
= is_active_controller('dashboards')
| ">
```

This not only is ugly and clunky--it doesn't work.

I've tried various options without success. Such as:

```
li class=is_active_controller('dashboards')
```

...as well as several other variations without success.

Comment: you can use `html2slim` gem. a good documentation here  https://github.com/slim-template/slim/wiki/Template-Converters-ERB-to-SLIM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
li class=(is_active_controller('dashboards'))
```

Comment: yeah--that's actually the code I included as not working--but turns out it works. This does too:  `li[class=is_active_controller('dashboards')]` - I had an issue with another element in the code.